# c++ Reliable way to remove all entries with UUID as the key

Tags: c++, components

So I have a bunch of std::unordered_maps that all have a common key but different datatypes for the data. I basically made a structure similar to a component based entity system, with the key being a entity class that contains a boost::uuid.

The adding works well but I am struggling with removing entire entities from the program. I can't find a reliable way to delete them without impairing running systems (I don't want to allow a delete in the middle of a frame to avoid one frame being glitched due to values being desynced or replaced with some default values) or that's terribly slow.

Right now I have a bool in the entity class and every frame the program goes through EVERY entity and checking if its set to true or not. IF yes the datapoint is removed from the map.

However I am not satisfied with it.

This is what the average entity looks like:

```
    class Entity{
private:
    boost::uuids::uuid uuid;
    bool protect = false;
    bool status = ENTITY_ALIVE;
public:
    Entity()
    :uuid(boost::uuids::random_generator()()){
    }
    const boost::uuids::uuid &operator ()()const{
        return this->uuid;
    }
    bool operator ==(const Entity &othr)const{
        return this->uuid==othr.uuid;
    }


    void copyComponents(const Entity &source,ComponentBase** mgrs, int c){
        std::cout<<"copying...\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < c; i ++){
            std::cout<<"-";
            mgrs[i]->copyTo(source,*this);
        }
    }
    void kill(){
        if(this->protect==false){
            this->status = ENTITY_DEAD;
        }
    }
    bool getStatus()const{
        return this->status;
    }
    void setProtection(bool status){
        this->protect = status;
    }

    bool getProtection(){
        return this->protect;
    }

    ~Entity(){
//        std::cout<<"ENTITY WAS DELETED!!!!!!!!!!!"<<"\n";
    }
};
struct EntityHasher{
    size_t operator()(const Entity& obj)const{
        return boost::uuids::hash_value((obj)());
    }

};
```

Ok and this is what the maps look like:

```
typedef typename std::unordered_map<std::reference_wrapper<const Entity>,List<std::shared_ptr<t>>,EntityHasher,std::equal_to<const Entity>> mapType;
```

The list is a custom class I made that simply stores things in a doubly linked list. Nothing to worry about. I made this since accessing data was easier than using unordered_multi map.

What I have tried:

- I have tried to store links to the classes containing the maps and simply directly having them delete it without much success.
- I have tried to have is so when a "dead" entity is accessed its being added to a vector in the class storing the unordered map and then later cleared in a separate function called "removeCorpses". However that lead to lesser used components being left on for way too long and it was generally just really unstable (maybe I made a mistake implementing it)

Please suggest some good ways of going about deleting a Entity in all maps having it as a key without messing with the active frame etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boost.MultiIndex to construct a map-like structure that keeps corpses arranged first in a secondary sequenced index so that they can be erased when appropriate:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c974360afcab113)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

template<typename Key,typename Value>
struct delayed_erasure_unordered_map_value
{
  Key           first;
  mutable Value second;
};

template<typename Key,typename Value>
using delayed_erasure_unordered_map_base=boost::multi_index_container<
  delayed_erasure_unordered_map_value<Key,Value>,
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<
      boost::multi_index::member<
        delayed_erasure_unordered_map_value<Key,Value>,
        Key,
        &delayed_erasure_unordered_map_value<Key,Value>::first
      >
    >,
    boost::multi_index::sequenced<>
  >
>;

template<typename Key,typename Value>
class delayed_erasure_unordered_map:
  public delayed_erasure_unordered_map_base<Key,Value>
{
  using base=delayed_erasure_unordered_map_base<Key,Value>;
public:
  using iterator=typename base::iterator;

  using base::base;

  void mark_for_erasure(iterator it) // marking same element twice is UB
  {
    auto pit=this->template project<1>(it);
    auto& index=this->template get<1>();
    index.relocate(index.begin(),pit);
    ++num_corpses;
  }

  void erase_marked()
  {
    auto& index=this->template get<1>();
    for(;num_corpses;--num_corpses)index.erase(index.begin());
  }

private:
  std::size_t num_corpses=0;
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  delayed_erasure_unordered_map<int,int> m=
    {{0,0},{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{6,6},{7,7},{8,8},{9,9}};

  for(auto it=m.begin(),end=m.end();it!=end;++it){
    if(it->first%2)m.mark_for_erasure(it);
  }
  m.erase_marked();

  for(const auto& x:m){
    std::cout<<"{"<<x.first<<","<<x.second<<"} ";
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
{0,0} {2,2} {4,4} {6,6} {8,8}
```